# Bootstrap. Высота изображений

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, изображения, grid

Всем привет. Возник вопрос. Как я могу создать сетку из изображений с разной высотой? Чтобы сетка была такой: [Grid](https://weatherless.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/css3-grid.jpg)

В Bootstrap 3 это вроде автоматически задается. В Bootstrap 4 все колонны с одинаковой высотой.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: С помощью grid и создавайте. Бутстрап (особенно 3-й, который на флоатах) здесь не поможет

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Я набросал Вам примерный вариант, как это можно сделать на grid:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 30px);
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #7cb2d8;
}
.grid-item1,
.grid-item2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
}
.grid-item3 {
  grid-row: 1 / 10;
}
.grid-item4 {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}
.grid-item5 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 10 / 12;
}
.grid-item6 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 10 / 12;
}
.grid-item7 {
  grid-row: 6 / 12;
}
.grid-item8 {
  grid-row: 6 / 10;
}
.grid-item9 {
  grid-row: 5 / 10;
}
.grid-item10 {
  grid-row: 5 / 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item9"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item10"></div>
</div>
```